# DC 21 Wisdom Saving Throw against fear- do I just always fail?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, saving-throw

The Ancient Red Dragon has an Action option:

> **Frightful Presence.** Each creature of the dragon's choice that is within 120 feet of the dragon and aware of it must succeed on a DC 21 Wisdom saving throw or become frightened for 1 minute. A creature can repeat the saving throw at the end of its turns ending the effect on itself on a success.

With a +0 to Wisdom and without proficiency in Wisdom Saving Throws, how can I hope to succeed against that? Even with Advantage and a Natural 20, my PC would still fail.

I know there are Magic Items like the Luck Stone and the Cloak of Protection that boosts saving throws but I'd still need to roll insane numbers to save against it.

**How can a character with +0 Wisdom ever overcome its fear of Ancient Red Dragons?**

This is a hypothetical question, I don't have a particular race, class or archetype in mind, neither is there a party composition. If one class is particularly good at resisting fear, I'd like to know.

Comment: At the risk of this question being too broad, would it not be too broad if I just take out anything that grants Advantage? Effectively, I'd be looking for just straight bonuses to resist fear.

Comment: advantage won't help you get over a 20.

Comment: @THiebert exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Here are (at least some) of the ways you can avoid being affected by the frightful presence. I've excluded features that give bonuses to saving throws, as I'm not sure how much it will actually benefit you if your mod is only +0, and I excluded anything that gives advantage against fear, because advantage cannot raise your maximum roll.

### Class Features

The Monk's Stillness of Mind (PHB 79)

> Starting at 7th level, you can use your action to end one effect on yourself that is causing you to be charmed or frightened.

The Beserker's mindless rage feature (PHB 49)

> Beginning at 6th level, you can’t be charmed or frightened while raging. Ifyou are charmed or frightened when you enter your rage, the effect is suspended for the duration of the rage.

**The Paladin's Aura of Courage (PHB 85)**

> Starting at 10th level, you and friendly creatures within 10 feet of you can’t be frightened while you are conscious.

This feature is probably the best one, since it doesn't cost any resources at all and it protects your friends as well. Thus, the Paladin is the best class for resisting fear, second to the Barbarian (as one might expect).

### Spells

Power Word Heal (PHB 266)

> If the creature is charmed, frightened, paralyzed, or stunned, the condition ends.

Calm Emotions (PHB 221)

> You can suppress any effect causing a target to be charmed or frightened. When this spell ends, any suppressed effect resumes, provided that its duration has not expired in the meantime.

The Heroes' Feast spell (PHB 250)

> A creature that partakes of the feast gains several benefits. The creature is cured of all diseases and poison, becomes immune to poison and being frightened, and makes all Wisdom saving throws with advantage.

Heroism (PHB 250)

> Until the spell ends, the creature is immune to being frightened and gains temporary hit points equal to your spellcasting ability modifier at the start of each of its turns.

Hallow (PHB 249)

> Second, you can bind an extra effect to the area. ...
>
> **Courage.** Affected creatures can’t be frightened while in the area.

### Magic Items

Blackrazor (DMG 216-7)

> While you hold the weapon. you are aware of the presence of Tiny or larger creatures within 60 feet of you that aren't constructs or undead. You also can't be charmed or frightened.

Comment: If you include bonuses to saving throws, Bless and Bardic Inspiration. You're also missing Heroism as a spell that provides immunity.

Comment: Monk's Stillness of the Mind can end frightened, as can the spell Dispel Evil and Good. The spell Hallow can also create an area of fear immunity.

Comment: I also found a couple features that can help against fear caused by certain creature types, but none include dragons, so i'm unsure if they belong in this answer or not.

Comment: @THiebert Sounds like you need to put up an answer. :P

Comment: I added Stillness of the Mind, but Dispel Evil and Good and Hallow are also specific to a handful of (non-draconic) creature types. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: The secondary effect of Hallow seems to apply to all creature types, but I will admit I was wrong about DEaG.

Comment: I didn't see the Courage secondary effect; you're right. I'll add that in as well.